# Finding arkose fun captcha callback

Tags: python, selenium, callback, 2captcha

I have been building my confidence with python by automating tasks with selenium. I am trying to automate logging into my [battle.net](https://account.battle.net/) account, yet when I click login it prompts for a fun captcha completion (it prompts the captcha after clicking log in).

So far I am able to get a valid akrose fun captcha token from 2captcha and insert it into the html of the page ([as per the 2captcha documentation](https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_funcaptcha_new)), however I can not find the callback function. I have spent a considerable amount of time searching for it throught the various scripts and in chrome developer network and console tabs. The 2captcha solver chrome extension is able to find the callback. So I also spent time looking through the scripts it uses, however I am unable to determine how it finds the callback function. I have tried asking 2captcha support, but to no avail.

I am after some help in finding it, as I feel I am clearly missing something or looking in the wrong place. Any piece of advice or direction would be greatly appreciated as I feel I have reached a standstill.

Thank you.